# Flutter Pageview swipe change background image with animation

Tags: flutter, image, animation, flutter-pageview

I working on a project where I have a Stack widget with a Container which has an image(this is the background of the app):

```
//Background image:
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage(background),
                fit: BoxFit.fill,
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

and a PageView widget that contains the page of the app.
How do I do that when the widget changes page, then the AssetImage(background) change the image with a faded animation?
Currently in the PageViews widget onPageChanged section I can change the background with multiple setStates:

```
onPageChanged: (index) {
              if (index == 0) {
                setState(() {
                  pageName = "Home";
                  background =
                      "lib/assets/Backgrounds/gradient_background_6.jpg";
                });
              } else if (index == 1) {
                setState(() {
                  pageName = "Coupons";
                  background =
                      "lib/assets/Backgrounds/gradient_background_5.jpg";
                });
              } else if (index == 2) {
                setState(() {
                  pageName = "Forum";
                  background =
                      "lib/assets/Backgrounds/gradient_background_4.jpg";
                });
              }
            },
```

but with this solution the background image just change without any animation. What is the best why to change image with faded, or any other animation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `AnimatedOpacity` for fade effect on background image, also you can fast or slow fade control with `duration` properties i already use in it

**Output:-**

[image]

**Code:-**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class PageViewExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const PageViewExample({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<PageViewExample> createState() => _PageViewExampleState();
}

class _PageViewExampleState extends State<PageViewExample>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  int currentIndex = 0;
  String background = "https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: PageView.builder(
        onPageChanged: (index) => setState(() {
          currentIndex = index;
          currentIndex == 1
              ? background = "https://picsum.photos/id/238/200/300"
              : currentIndex == 2
                  ? background = "https://picsum.photos/id/239/200/300"
                  : background = "https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300";
        }),
        physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
        itemCount: 3,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return AnimatedOpacity(
            duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
            opacity: currentIndex == index ? 1.0 : 0.1,
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: NetworkImage(background),
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use SwitchAnimation, but you need a key you can use the index like a "key" this is a example

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class Examp extends StatelessWidget {
  const Examp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: 
       AnimatedSwitcher(
        key: index,
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 700),
        child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage(background),
                fit: BoxFit.fill,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

Tell if this code worked for you

Comment: I just implemented in my code, but unfortunately it has the same effect as my solution, it doesn't have any animated change between the images.